# @Value in SpringBoot in 2.1.1.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have this value defined in the `application.properties` file

```
tdk.date.format=yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'.000Z'
```

that I use in this class:

```
public class TdkDateUtils {


    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(CryptoDateUtils.class);


    @Value("${tdk.date.format}")
    private static String tdkDateFormat;

    public static boolean afterYesterday2(String strDate) throws ParseException {

        LOG.debug("tdkDateFormat -> {} ", tdkDateFormat);

        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat(tdkDateFormat);  
        Date yesterdayDate = Date.from(Instant.now().minus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS));
        return format.parse(strDate).after(yesterdayDate);
    }
}
```

but is null

Comment: Is `TdkDateUtils` a `component` or `service` type bean ?? I do not see any annotation on it. Spring will not be able to inject values to it if spring is not able to scan the class and generate a bean out of it.

Comment: I do not think your issue is due to Spring Boot's version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TdkDateUtils` is a utility class and `afterYesterday2` is a static method. It exists entirely outside of your application Spring context, annotations like `@Value` won't be processed here.

For `@Value` to work you would have to make `TdkDateUtils` a bean as only Spring beans will be processed by `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer`. Alternatively could read and set the property yourself in `TdkDateUtils` static initialization block but it goes against Spring philosophy of dependency injection.

Answer (score 2):

Spring doesn’t allow to inject value into static variables. Create a non-static setter method to inject the value.

```
private static String tdkDateFormat;

@Value("${tdk.date.format}")
public void setDateFormat(String s){
   tdkDateFormat = s;
}
```